# java subtype-like relationship between generic classes

Tags: java, generics

I have Interface called A, which extends another interface B

and i have this code:

```
class myMap<T extends B> {
    private Map<PluginTypes, T> map;

    public myMap() {
        map = new HashMap<PluginTypes, T>();
        map.put(PluginTypes.ICustomPublishingNeedsService,
                A.class);
    }

}
```

i am getting this compiler error on the put function:

```
The method put(PluginTypes, T) in the type Map<PluginTypes,T> is not applicable for the arguments (PluginTypes, Class<A>)
```

#### For the record

i already tried this

```
private Map<PluginTypes, Class<T>> map2;

    public myMap(int i) {
        map2 = new HashMap<PluginTypes, Class<T>>();
        map2.put(PluginTypes.ICustomPublishingNeedsService,
                (Class<T>) ICustomPublishingNeeds.class);
    }
```

it is working, but it is not safe, i would rather prefer if you can help me to fine my mistake in the first code

Comment: What is `map` intended to store?

Comment: @sp00m the keys are enum and the values of the keys are interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

It is because Class doesnt extends A or B

`myMap<T extends B>` is saying that the type of this parameter is going to be of type `B` (or one of its subclasses). You are passing it a `Class`. `Class` doesn't extend B.

Comment: may you tell me a possible solution please?

Comment: Simple solution would be `myMap<T extends Class>`

Comment: that is not safe, i need a specific interface, which is Plugin

Comment: I need T to extends a specific interface, not extend Class

Comment: Then dont put a `Class` object in your map. Your logic seems wrong. Maybe your map should be `Map<T,Class>`

Comment: maybe that is the correct answer, i should have tried to put class in my maps.

Comment: anyway, i am still trying to find a solution

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I really need to store class not instances, if you need to know why, kindly check my previous questions. unfortunately, I ended up by a user telling me to have a basic java tutorial.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I got that the values of the map must be Class, but can't i restrict (bound) it to specific classes? not all classes, i would like if there is a way to accept classes from specific Interface

Comment: @T.J.Crowder please what mistake did i do to have been down vote here one and in the previous question two users down vote me

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the purpose of the map is to have an interface for each enum value. now i got u, it is not possible to bound for classes from specific interface. thank you very much.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it seems we can bound the class, `Map<PluginTypes, Class<? extends IPlugin>> map = new HashMap<PluginTypes, Class<? extends IPlugin>>();` works perfect :)

Comment: @user489041 please check my last comment

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: Sorry, yes, I was assuming dynamic loading of these plugin classes. If you do dynamic loading, you'll have to check and then cast when adding them. BTW, it's perfectly valid to answer your own question and accept that answer (SO will make you wait two days to accept).